# Is there a way for git-log to not show any tags and/or branches?

Tags: git

I am dealing with some projects that have do not have sourcecode among many other projects that *have* changing sourcecode. We also tag/branch all of the projects, together, over time. Therefore, the unchanging projects have a mountain of tags/branches on the tip commit. My current git is decorating the commits with tags/branches by default and, whereas this is usually preferable, the projects that have not changed in a very long time will have pages of tags/branches that need to be skipped over.

How can I run a git-log and *not* print tags/branches? I am primarily interested in hiding all of the tags, but I do not know what my options are.

Thanks.

Comment: Specify your own `--pretty` format.

Comment: Let's just hold-out to see if someone knows of something simpler and easier to remember.

Comment: It might be better to deal with this by making a repo for the overall project that brings together everything using `git-submodules`. Then instead of tagging every single sub-repo, you just tag the one big repo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option to show branches and tags is `--decorate`. You can turn it off with `--no-decorate`. You can customize the format with `--format`. See [`git-log`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks.